# IsNumeric does not work in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, isnumeric

Getting very annoyed with this simple query...
I need to add an offset to a varchar, if it's a number and do nothing is it is not.
For this reason I've created the following function in SQL-server.
I then extract the answer with:
`select dbo.OffsetKPL("100",200)`

However this does not work, I get the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '100'.

The code for the function is as follows...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[OffsetKPL](
  @kpl varchar(20)
  ,@offset int = 0
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN   
  DECLARE @uitkomst varchar(20);

  set @uitkomst = @kpl;
  if not(@offset = 0) begin
    if (IsNumeric(@uitkomst) = 1) begin
      set @uitkomst = cast((cast(@kpl as int) + @offset) as varchar);
    end;
end;

RETURN @uitkomst;

END
```

What's wrong? nowhere does it state that IsNumeric does not accept a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes for strings!

```
select dbo.OffsetKPL('100',200)
```

If you have `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` on (the default) things in double quotes are expected to be object names.

`isnumeric` may not be what you need though as all kinds of unexpected things return `1` for this.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('$'), ISNUMERIC('.'), 
       ISNUMERIC('12d5'), ISNUMERIC(','), ISNUMERIC('1e1')
```

See [IsNumeric() Broken? Only up to a point](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2011/01/13/98746.aspx) for some discussion on this point.

Comment: Yep that works, I was really stuckenstein for a while there, anyway that's what I get for taking off my tinfoil hat.

Comment: I know about the borken state of IsNumeric, but for the purpose I need it for I suffices never thought about the " issues, usually work in MySQL.